# In VSCode, how do I use Test Runner to run a Java JUnit test within the editor?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit, test-runner, visual-studio-test-runner

I have a Java project on VSCode for Windows and I have installed the Test Runner plugin ...

[image]

I would like to be able to run a test file from the editor and see the results.  In Eclipse, I can right click on the test file but when I open the test file in the editor

[image]

I don't see any option to right click and run my test file and I don't see any "Run Test" text hovering above my test file class, as some other posts seem to suggest.  What is the right way to run a test from the editor?  I'm not tied to Test Runner for Java.  I'm open to using other extensions.

Comment: Please show more of the code so that others can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The [Test Runner for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test) extension supports the following test frameworks:
>
> - [JUnit 4](https://junit.org/junit4/) (v4.8.0+)
> - [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/) (v5.1.0+)
> - [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/) (v6.9.13.3+)

You must first [enable testing and adding test framework JARs to your project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing#_enable-testing-and-adding-test-framework-jars-to-your-project). Then in the ***Testing*** panel on the left, you can see the test list of the project and test it. A Test button is also displayed to the left of the test script.

[image]

*There are more details you can look at this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing)*.